# CSS nth-child,crossing tree branches

Tags: css

I have a list with category headers, and items nested in those headers. If I do

```css
#list .item:nth-child(1):before{content:"1";}
```

the first item in each category gets prefixed with a 1. This is somewhat unexpected. I guess I am looking for an `nth-item()` plugin.

What are my options given I do not control the html, its changing dynamically and I don't want to monitor it with jQuery. I was hoping for a CSS solution.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kT5y5/1/)

Comment: that is how the `:nth-child` selector works... it work based on the index of the current item based on its parent

Comment: I need the CSS equivalent of `.eq()`. I dont know how many items per category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alternatively use a [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)

http://jsfiddle.net/6tN5U/

```css
body {
    counter-reset: item;
}

.item{
    margin-left:20px;
}
#items .item:before{counter-increment: item; content: counter(item) " ";}
```

Comment: That looks cool but my html is dynamic. How do I know when to reset counter if its constantly changing?

Comment: @MarkRobbins `counter-reset` is how you reset it.  With this code it just resets once on the body, but you can change your `items` id to a class and reset on that. like so: http://jsfiddle.net/6tN5U/1/

Comment: @Joseph Can I put the reset in the #list wrapper? Or if I put it in .item:first-child will it work with dynamic html?

Comment: @MarkRobbins I recommend placing the reset in a wrapping element.  See my previous comment.

Comment: @Joseph Shoot, wait. Is there a way I can have it do 1234567890abcedfg...z then stop? LOL. Its a hotkey prompt.

Comment: @MarkRobbins That's a good question.  Let me see if I can figure out a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55543/discussion-between-mark-robbins-and-joseph-marikle).